# Trigger the before/after Submit Scripts through External record create API

Tags: netsuite

External system(SharePoint) is making SOAP API call to create a record in Netsuite, on which creation of records upon meeting a field criteria a beforesubmit script should be triggered in updating field values. When a record is created through Netsuite UI the beforesubmit runs fine but when it is getting created through API call seems like workflow is not running.

So is it something like we cannot invoke Workflow/beforeSubmit process in sfdc through external API call? If so what thinigs should be done to trigger Workflow/beforeSubmit process through external SOAP API calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a system level preference for this.

Setup > Integration > SOAP Web Services Preferences

check "Run Server Suitescript and Trigger Workflows"

It's off by default.

The preference can also be managed on a request basis.

e.g. by adding the following to the Preferences element in the SOAP Headers

```
<runServerSuiteScriptAndTriggerWorkflows>true</runServerSuiteScriptAndTriggerWorkflows>
```

Comment: It’s already enabled

Comment: Check in your System > Integration > Web Services Usage Log. 

See if the request for an add or update explicitly sends that element with a false value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Context filtering of the userEvent script that do the beforesubmit?

Comment: Yes I have tried it but still not triggered